# Excel Add-In: Table OnChange event sometimes does not trigger after cell value change

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, office-js

I am developing an Excel add-in that allows to synchronize changed table cell values with external environment using table `onChanged`. And noticed quite annoying result, if user changes values with a high speed, some values skipped. I wrote a simple snippet for changing color after table cell changed, and some cells were not change the color if you type is so fast. Is it fixable?

Here is an example:

[image]

Event doesn't trigger for cells #15 and #18 at all.

and the code snippet:

```
public cellChange = async  (event: Excel.TableChangedEventArgs): Promise<any> =>
{
    try
    {
        await Excel.run({delayForCellEdit: true}, async context =>
        {
            try
            {
                context.runtime.enableEvents = false;

                if (event.changeType === Excel.DataChangeType.rangeEdited)
                {
                    let worksheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
                    let address = event.address;
                    let str = "Cell address: " + address + " START";
                    var start = new Date().getTime();
                    
                    let rng = worksheet.getRange(address);
                    rng.format.fill.color = "#D0DC94";
                    await context.sync();

                    var end = new Date().getTime();
                    var time = end - start;
                    str = str + `-END:${time}ms`;

                    console.log(str);
                }
            }
            catch (error)
            {
                let e: Error = error;
                let mssg = e.message;
            }
            finally
            {
                context.runtime.enableEvents = true;
            }
            return context.sync();
        });
    }
    catch (error)
    {
        let e: Error = error;
        let mssg = e.message;

        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error)
        {
            console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I notice that you called `context.runtime.enableEvents = false`, as we are running in aync mode, the event may be disable when user did some change before you call  `context.runtime.enableEvents = true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the change happens between `context.runtime.enableEvents = false` and `context.runtime.enableEvents = true`

1. `context.runtime.enableEvents = false` is called at the beginning of the function
2. And then `await context.sync()` is called, which may provide chance that user would change during this time
3. `context.runtime.enableEvents = true` is called. resume listening to the event.

From your code, I think you would like to avoid trigger `onChange` event from your own code. so the suggestion is to use `triggerSource` to identify whether the event is trigger by your own code or not.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheetchangedeventargs?view=excel-js-preview#triggerSource